# cluster::daisy drops labels

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, r-daisy

I am trying to cluster data using cluster::daisy function and dissimilarity matrix. The data looks as shown below.

```
> head(score_mat_unique_3)
         ID_1       ID_2    Score
1: 1000035849 1000532512 2.49e-60
2: 1000035849 1000682765 3.87e-08
3: 1000086994 1000658924 8.90e-18
4: 1000234640 1000535109 1.20e-87
5: 1000235015 1000754236 6.29e-34
6: 1000258002 1000598768 8.34e-36
```

Score shows how different the objects are (the larger the value, the more different objects.), so I use the dissimilarity matrix and the daisy function.

```
diss3 <- daisy(score_mat_unique_3, metric = "gower")
```

But when I try to plot hclust, some numbers are printed instead of ID.

```
fit3 <- hclust(diss3, method = "ward.D2")
plot(fit3)
```

[image]
Accordingly, information about objects in clusters is lost. How can I return information about the initial IDs and understand which IDs are in the clusters?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `labels` argument to `plot`.  Since you don't provide your data, I will illustrate with the built-in iris data.

```
DAT = iris[sample(26),1:4]
fit3 = hclust(dist(DAT))

plot(fit3, labels=LETTERS)
```

[image: Dendrogram with labels]

In your case, try `plot(fit3, labels=score_mat_unique_3$ID_1)`

Comment: Thanks! It works for plot. But how can i write IDs in each cluster in variable (or file)? I use `groups <- cutree(fit3, k=6)
groups_rected <- rect.hclust(fit3, k=6, border="red")`  and try to see `groups_rected`, but there again, instead of ID, numbers are written, as on the graph.